# Installing mongify, ruby version >= 1.9.3 required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, rubygems, activesupport

I'm trying to install mongify in order to import data from a sqlite db to a mongo db.

My problem is that i've installed ruby version 2.1.11 and the rvm 1.9.3 version but running the command `sudo gem install mongify` keeps showing me this error:

```
'activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3'
```

I don't know what to do anymore. Can you help me please?

What I do:

```
/bin/bash --login
rvm use 1.9.3 #show me the message 'using /home/rodolfo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448
sudo gem install mongify
```

And I get:

```
ERROR: Error installing mongify:
       activesupport requires ruby version >= 1.9.3
```

Comment: When you do `ruby -v`, what version is shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gems should be installed on a project specific and not as root. You should rvm to manage gems on per project basis. [Install Rvm from here](https://rvm.io/rvm/install)

When you cd into a project folder, check for `ruby -v`, It should give you the specific ruby version which the project is using which must be greater than 1.9.3. Now run `gem install mongify` which will install the specific gem.

when you run `'sudo gem install mongify'`It uses the default version of ruby which may not be the version inside the application. you can change it if you are using rvm.

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved a similar problem using the following commands:

```
$ sudo su
$ source /home/user/.bashrc
$ /bin/bash --login
$ rvm --default use 1.9.3
```

You may able to install your bundle normally.

Answer (score 0):

if u already installed rvm in root then go to your app directory
ex: cd sampleapp
then type this command
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
then install bundle